# Dataset for hand gesture recognition

Tags: image-processing

I need a dataset for my future project based on image processing, hand recognition. I need a minimum of 5 hand position and orientation and a minumim of 200 images per set. 
I want to know if there are websites where I can find a great variety of datasets.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says specifically that this sort of question is off-topic. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to search here: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/Imagedbase.htm#gesture.
I needed this for a project too and I found a lot of variations here. It also depends on what kind of gestures you are looking for, but I think you will find here what you need.